# Get all seller transactions using eBay api

Tags: c#, ebay-api

How to get all items and transactions made by the seller on eBay for all time. I can successfully receive all transaction details for the past 10 days using the following code:

```
// Getting sold items
var durationSpecifiedeBaySellingCall = new GetMyeBaySellingCall(apiContext)
{
    SoldList = new ItemListCustomizationType
    {
        DurationInDays = 10,
        DurationInDaysSpecified = true,
        Include = true
    },

    DetailLevelList = new DetailLevelCodeTypeCollection
    {
        DetailLevelCodeType.ReturnAll
    }
};
durationSpecifiedeBaySellingCall.Execute();
```

but I'm not able to receive all transactions for the past 10 years, for example, when replace the value of `DurationInDays` with 3650 instead of 10. `durationSpecifiedeBaySellingCall.SoldListReturn` is null. How can I properly get the list of all user transactions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are using the GetMyeBaySelling API call, the documentation states that you can only pull a Max of 60 Days.

[eBay Documentation GetMyeBaySelling](http://developer.ebay.com/devzone/xml/docs/reference/ebay/getmyebayselling.html#Request.DeletedFromSoldList.DurationInDays)

Comment: Yeah, thanks, i've kinda figured this out already... so there isn't any possible way to get all existed transactions for all time? Does eBay even keep this kind of information?

Comment: There is something called the Market Research API, but the chances of getting access to it are pretty much nil, and I do not think they let you query more than 365 days.

You might want to try scraping Terapeak if its just one seller that you want info on.